# In Java how to display function parameters when the function is called at much higher level?

Tags: java

For practicing algorithm questions, I set up my Java code like:
ProblemClass.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new ProblemClass().new Solution();
        Utils.isEqual(solution.function("abc"), "def");
}
public class {
    public Solution {
        public String function(String s) {}
    }
}
```

The Utils.isEqual is basically wrapping a comparison like:

```
    public static void isEqual(Object actual, Object expected) {
        if (actual == null && expected == null || actual.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println("Pass.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail. Expecting: [" + expected + "] Actual result: [" + actual + "]");
        }
    }
```

When I run hundred of test cases, all I see on the command prompt is:

```
Pass.
Pass.
Pass.
Pass.
...
Fail. Expecting: [false] Actual result: [true]
...
```

I don't know what test case has failed. I want to have some indication of *what* test has failed. I am open to other suggestions. So far, I thought maybe there is a way to display the parameters passed into `function` when calling `isEqual` through something like Reflection. I could not find a clear answer on that.

Lastly, I want to keep everything in the main() so all my tests and code is in one place as opposed to have a unit test class that I have to manage.

Comment: You could include a "message" with the assertion. But would it not be easier to use a testing framework, such as JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: How is this question similar to "How can I get the current stack trace in Java?" ???

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I would guess because if you dump the stack trace in your assertion then you can follow it to exactly which test failed. But I still recommend using a testing framework if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access a parameter your caller passed to another function: Method parameters are stored only while the method is still executing; once a method has completed execution, the storage that held its parameters is reclaimed and reused for other purposes (such as the parameters / local variables for the next function to execute).

Therefore you must change the structure of your code so this value is somehow passed to the function that needs it. A simple way is to add an additional parameter:

```
public static void assertEquals(String actual, String input, String expected) {
    if (Objects.equals(actual, expected) {
        System.out.println(input + ": pass");
    } else {
        System.out.println(input + ": failed. Expected: " + expected + ", but got " + actual);
    }
}
```

and calling it like:

```
assertEquals(solution.function("abc"), "abc", "def");
```

That works, but requires passing the input twice. One way to avoid that is passing the solution rather than invoking its method directly:

```
check(solution, "abc", "def");
```

where

```
check(Solution solution, String input, String expected) {
    String actual = solution.function(input);
    if (Objects.equals(expected, actual)) {
        System.out.println(input + ": pass");
    } else {
        System.out.println(input + ": failed. Expected: " + expected + ", but got " + actual);
    }
 }
```

However, that still requires `check` to know which method to call (`function` is our example). If you need `check` to work with arbitrary methods, you can pass the method itself rather than merely the object that defines it:

```
check(solution::function, "abc", "def");
```

where

```
interface TestCase {
    String func(String input);
}

void check(TestCase test, String input, String expectedOutput) {
    String output = test.func(input);
    // compare and print as before
}
```

All that said, in professional code you would probably be using a test framework like junit rather than reinventing the wheel.